# How to find the length of a particular column of a table in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite

I am using sqlite database in  my project.

My table structure will be almost like this

```
id  cid values

1   1   value1
2   1   value2
3   1   value3
4   1   value4
5   2   value1
6   2   value2
7   3   value1
8   3   value2
9   3   value3
```

so I want all the values of the same **cid**,how should I code it?

**My query:**

```
tx.executeSql("SELECT cid,value FROM table where cid="+cid_value, [], querySuccess, errorCB,cid_value);
```

because,when I tried it the following manner,

```
var details = results.rows.length;
console.log("db test value:"+results.rows.item(cid_value).value);
for (var i=cid_value; i<details; i++)
{
cidinstance=results.rows.item(i).cid;
var valueinstance=results.rows.item(i).value;
document.getElementById("s"+i+"cause").innerHTML=valueinstance;
console.log("cid= "+cidinstance +   "valueinstance= "+valueinstance);
}
```

then **when i=cid_value(cid_value=1)** targeting cid=1, where we have four values I get just **3 values**.but,if i put **i=0**,then I get **4 values**

when **i=cid_value(cid_value=2)** targeting cid=2,i get the following

```
01-01 05:45:38.687: I/Web Console(2425): JSCallback: Message from Server:  SQLitePluginTransaction.queryCompleteCallback('1104538538488000','1104538538491000', [{"value":"value1","cid":"2"},{"value":"value22","id":"6","cid":"2"}]); at file:///android_asset/www/cordova-2.1.0.js:3726.
```

**The Problem is,I am getting the values when I get the message from the server as JS Callback. not from the for loop**

Please,suggest me ways to solve the problem!.guide me to find a way out.

Comment: it's not a good practice to perform logic into your view

Comment: @MuhammadRamahy,sorry I did not get you.

Comment: for (var i=cid_value; i<details; i++) ? Why i=cid_value, not i = 0?

Comment: @FrankyYang when i give i=cid_value.if cid=1 has 4 values...only 3 values are printing.as it is considering the 1st row as row 0. when cid=2...it prints only 1 value and says cannot find the value.

Comment: as Franky said, why not i = 0? if you run that query with cid = 1, you correctly get 4 results: to print all 4 results, you need to start the for cycle from 0 to results.length, not from i=cid_value

Comment: @BeNdErR, **it works only with cid=1 not with the rest cid values**

Comment: @FrankyYang, **BeNdErR**,no it is not working as you both have suggested

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the number of rows where a particular CID is listed, you need to use the COUNT function in SQLite.

So your statement would be ::

```
SELECT COUNT(values) FROM TableName WHERE cid=1
```

That will give you the count directly. You don't need any code to do the calculations yourself.

Comment: Well your question says, how do you find the "length" of a particular column of table in Javascript. So I was demo'ing how to find the number of inputs that are returned depending on the cid value provided using the COUNT function in SQLite.